# How do you make a water shader?

Tags: shaders, lighting, water

I'm working on a minecraft-like world and recently saw this video with a water shader.  I searched but couldn't find any good info on how to do something similar.  Maybe I'm just googling the wrong thing.  Does anyone have any resources on how to do something like this?

[minecraft water shader video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dHe9Brqp5HY&feature=player_embedded)

Answer (score 1):

A long time ago, when I was programming similar water simulation, I used [this as a source](http://en.pudn.com/downloads130/sourcecode/graph/detail554563_en.html). It's written in C++/OpenGL. You can find there PDF with description and also source codes.

You can see, there are faked waves - if you don't want them there, you just don't have to use "noise" textures.

Comment: And if you want better (more realistic) water simulation, you can use one of these: http://vterrain.org/Water/